# Escaping '\' for use with Java replaceAll method

Tags: java, escaping, replace

I am getting some weird results when using the replaceAll method of the String class.

The string *query* contains the following: `@cm:name:"hello"`

If I say `query.replaceAll(":", "\\:");`

I would expect the following result: `@cm\:name\:"hello"`

Instead I get: `@cm:name:"hello"`.  The original content.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `replaceAll(..)` for non-regex replaces. Use `replace(..)` instead.

Then, be sure to have:

```
query = query.replace(":", "\\:");
```

because `String` is immutable - i.e. if you just call the method without assigning the result, you get nothing - the internal state of the object won't change.

Comment: I simplified this, I am using a regex expression.

Comment: well, you went too far in your simplification, producing a non-compiling code that does not illustrate your problem. Please update the question with relevant details - i.e. the actual code.

Comment: sorry I didn't realize that I needed to escape it in this editor.

Comment: you don't have to, but you'd have to use the ` sign to enclose code. I did it for you. Now provide the whole code, (if the answer doesn't work in its current form)

Answer (score 1):

There are two simple rules.

1. The Java compiler requires two blackslashes to represent a single backslash in a string literal .
2. Regular expressions require two backslashes to represent a single backslash in a regular expression.

So if you want a string literal to contain a regular expression single backslash you have to write *four*.

Answer (score 0):

The escape sequence for `\` is `\\`. So, you'd write this:

```
query.replaceAll(":", "\\:");
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape the slash

`query.replaceAll(":","\\:");`